# Insert file path into a large number of files

Tags: html, text, replace, path

I need to insert individual file paths and file names into a huge number of HTML files.  The path should be entered right after the `</title>` tag.

What is the quickest way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1

```
const fs = require("fs");
const nodePath = require('path');
const path = 'C:\\Users\\Sudhakar_r_R\\Desktop\\test';

function change(path) {
    const files = fs.readdirSync(path);
    files.forEach((i) => {
        let x = nodePath.join(path, i);
        if (fs.statSync(x).isFile()) {
            fs.readFile(x, 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
                if (err) throw err;
                let newStuff = data.replace('</title>', `</title><!-- fullpath: ${x} filename: ${nodePath.basename(x)} path: ${nodePath.dirname(x)} -->`);
                fs.writeFile(x, newStuff, 'utf-8', function (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log(x,"done");
                });
            })
        }
        else {
            change(x);
        }
    });
}

change(path);
```

Solution 2 (using '[jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom)')

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const fs = require("fs");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
JSDOM.fromFile("./old.html", { runScripts: "dangerously" }).then(dom => {
    let node = dom.window.document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0];
    // you can create html elements or put it in string format
    node.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '</title><script src="test.js"></script>');
    fs.writeFile('new.html', dom.serialize(), 'utf-8', function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Now, you can check the output');
    });
});
```

Comment: I am not trying to insert those strings into DOM.  I need to have them permanently saved in the HTML files.

Comment: @KnocksX both solutions do that only (2nd answer just modifies in the DOM way and then stores)  [old.html -> new.html]

Comment: @KnocksX output will be like <!-- fullpath: C:\Users\Sudhakar_r_R\Desktop\test\old.html filename: old.html path: C:\Users\Sudhakar_r_R\Desktop\test --> after the </title>